# How to disable default error response for Api Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, versioning, .net-6.0

Good evening, everybody. Trying to implement Api Versioning for my project. Faced with the problem that receiving default errors template response for request. **Look code 1**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
        "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:5003/v2.3' does not support the API version '2.3'.",
        "innerError": null
    }
}
```

But I have my own error response template that want to receive.

```
{
"traceId": "0HMF1NONVN8SF:00000002",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "",
            "source": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

As I understand I could implement my own ErrorResponseProvider, but could I avoid doing that?

How could I can disable ErrorResponse for **ApiVersionOptions**?
My api version configuration:

```
 services
   .AddApiVersioning(opt =>
                {
                    opt.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
                    opt.UseApiBehavior = false;
                    opt.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersion.Default;
                    opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                })
                .AddVersionedApiExplorer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
                    opt.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                });
```

Versions:

.NET 6

ASP.NET Core 6

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I didn't find the way to disable it. However, I found the solution for my case. First of all, I implemented my CustomErrorResponseProvider for ErrorResponses.

```
 public class CustomErrorResponseProvider : DefaultErrorResponseProvider
    {
        public override IActionResult CreateResponse(ErrorResponseContext context)
        {
            switch (context.ErrorCode)
            {
                case "UnsupportedApiVersion":
                    throw new UnsupportedApiVersionException("Url", context.Message);
            }

            return base.CreateResponse(context);
        }
    }
```

Than started throw necessary exception from it. And that's all!

As my middleware looks like **this**(img below), my ErrorHandlingMiddleware didn't catch an exception, because it was generated by default api versioning error handler.   [image]